# Why is kilo k but Mega M?

Tags: conventions, units, si-units

I was recently updating a piece of software with a pull-down menu for frequency units. It had Hz, kHz, MHz, GHz, and THz. Consistency is important in user interfaces, so I decided to update the table. I was not absolutely sure whether that first letter should be uppercase or lowercase for frequencies, though, so I checked Wikipedia.

Much to my surprise, I discovered that [the original software is correct](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hertz). Forget consistency, [kilo is always abbreviated as k, and mega as M, giga as G and so forth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_prefix).

My question is: Why?

Comment: Because "m" was already taken for "milli".

Comment: FYI, Wiki has an article on the [metric prefixes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_prefix). "deca (da)" and "hecto (h)" are other multipliers that get lower-case prefixes but indicate multipliers greater than 1.

Comment: I just did a web search on this, figuring it'd be easy pickings.  I'm not finding any clear reason.  The only reason I've seen anyone claim is that 'K' is the symbol for Kelvin, a temperature unit.  However, that explanation didn't quite suit my needs.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about terminology conventions rather than actual physics.

Comment: @CortAmmon Note that there are many other pairs of prefix and unit: mm for millimetre (usual), TT for teratesla (do not try this at home) or e.g. GG for gigagray (do not try this at home either). I guess that "k" for "kilo" is just for a historical reason. It even pairs with "k" - the Boltzmann constant!

Comment: @Qmechanic Is there a SE where this would be valid?  I, myself, am rather interested in an answer.

Comment: @CortAmmon, [History of Science and Mathematics](http://hsm.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: FWIW, the "k" prefix (also "c", "m", and "$\mu$") dates from 1795 according to wiki. "M" was introduced in 1873, and all the other capitalized prefixes were introduced (or at least standardized) in 1960 or later.

Comment: http://www.spe.org/authors/docs/metric_standard.pdf Extracted from there: G for giga; g for gram.  K for kelvin; k for kilo.  M for mega; m for milli. N for newton; n for nano. T for tera; t for tonne (metric ton).   There are only so many letters and historically some are already taken.

Comment: *"I was not absolutely sure [...] so I checked Wikipedia."* ::blinks:: While I would go to Wikipedia first, too, that would just be to get a link to something actually authoritative.